# What is the maximum length of a mongodb query?

Tags: mongodb

I will execute a big query so i want to know what is the maximum length of a mongodb query ?

Comment: Do you mean the size of the query object you're passing into the `find` method?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The maximum size of a document, which is what you are constructing when you create a query is 16MB.  You can see that, and other limits here:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/

Comment: Query object passing into the  find method can be maximum size of 16 MB ?

Comment: Any document (in recent versions, was lower previously) is limited to 16MB, so yes.

Comment: [http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Querying](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Querying) I found this helpful. You are right @Adamc thanks

Comment: @OnkarJanwa What did you find there? I couldn't size any information about query size limit?

Comment: It's not explicitly stated, but the link provided by @OnkarJanwa does allude to "query filter documents" - this is perhaps a slightly more helpful link: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#other-uses-of-the-document-structure which describes that MongoDB uses a document to store query filter parameters.