# MongoDB: fastest way to compare two large sets

Tags: mongodb, bloom-filter, large-data

I have a MongoDB collection with more than 20 millions documents (and growing fast). Some document have an 'user_id' (others, don't).

I regularly need to check if some user_id exists in the collection. But there is a lot of 'some'. 10K to 100K.

How would you do that?

The first thought is to have a big query:

```
$or : [ { 'user_id' : ... } , { ... } , ... ]
```

With all my 10K to 100K ids... But it's very slow, and I don't think it's the better way to do it. Someone told me about Redis' bloom filters, but it seems that Mongo does not do that.

Do you see a better way to do it? Like with bloom filters, a < 100% accuracy is acceptable in my case.

Comment: MongoDB supports filtering using $match if you use the aggregation framework. You may want to use [sparse](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-sparse/) indexes.

Comment: If I understand it well, the question is _"how to write a query to find the intersection between a huge set of values and the set of values from a collection"_. The key point being how to pass that "huge set" of values to compare with.

Comment: Somehow related: there is apparently a 16MB limit on the query size -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11688658/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-mongodb-query

Comment: You can always deploy your own bloom filters. As long as you do not remove documents.

Comment: (damn 5 minute limit) Though keep in mind, it's not a silver bullet. You will filter out users that are not in the database, but you still have to query those, that pass the filter.

Comment: @Hakan, sorry but I don't see how using the aggregation would be faster than a `$or []` query? @Sylvain For now, I don't have any issue with the size of my query. it's just very slow, but the query works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using `$in` for set comparison:

```
db.users.find({ _id : { $in : [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ] } })
```

If you have an index on the field you are searching over, the operation should be fast. If you don't have an index, and you anticipate needing to repeat that query often, you should definitely build one. As mentioned in the comments, a sparse index would suit your collection if the user_id field is only present in some documents.

I did a benchmark in IPython on a collection with ~200M documents, on a test database on a relatively high spec laptop:

```
import random
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient()
db = client["anonymised"]

# generate 100K random ids for testing purposes
ids = [ random.randint(0, int(1e6)) for i in range 100000 ]

%time db.users.count({ "_id" : { "$in" : ids } })
CPU times: user 182 ms, sys: 75.5 ms, total: 257 ms
Wall time: 16.1 s
# returns 32631
```

If you want to improve on this, you would have to look at sharding your database to keep a more important fraction in active memory. In a production environment with the entire working set in memory, this operation would presumably be significantly faster.

By contrast, the '$or' approach you initially took:

```
query = [ { "_id" : v } for v in ids ]

%time db.users.count({ "$or" : query })
CPU times: user 1.4 s, sys: 682 ms, total: 2.08 s
Wall time: 35min 30s
```